# Do questions disappear from old Area 51 proposals?

Tags: bug, area-51, commitment-phase

I went to restart a proposal on Area 51 that was closed, and when I was viewing the [old proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26843/military), I noticed something strange: there were very few questions with 10 score or more.

An Area 51 proposal needs 40 questions with 10+ score to move on to the commitment phase (and the proposal was *closed* while in commitment phase, so obviously it made it there). But when you look at ["all" example questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26843/military?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top), you notice only 49 *total* questions, and a *mere 10* questions with score of 10 or more. What happened to the good questions?

Comment: Probably due to lower requirement in the past?

Comment: Were only 10 questions required in the past? The proposal was started 2 years ago, that is true.